# Git push to DigitalOcean from Bitbucket or Cloud9

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket, production, cloud9-ide

I'm making site on `Cloud9` IDE and I can't find the way to easy push my production code to `DigitalOcean` `droplet` server. Maybe there is some simple way I could do it as easy as it is to push code to `Heroku` from `Cloud9`. With simple command from `Cloud9` console.

All my `git` code lives in Bitbucket so maybe you have ideas how to connect it to `DigitalOcean`?

Hope to hear how you do these production "pushes". You probably have well known techniques for these things.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first, easy, option is to pull instead of push. Just do a

```
git clone
```

or a

```
git pull
```

On the droplet.

The harder way is to do a continuous integration (CI) environment such as Jenkins or CruiseControl. You are unlikely to find this functionality in a hosted git environment such as GitHub or BitBucket.

Some reading:

http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/

https://jenkins-ci.org/

Comment: I installed git on droplet, but I don't know how to register or add credentials  of bitbucket so I can use this command. Maybe you know?

Comment: Oh, simpler question then. Basically you aren't sure how to check it out?

Try reading the official docs: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Clone+a+repository

Comment: i learned to clone my git. Thanks. Bad i encountered other problem that i can't find solution for :D

Answer (score 1):

You could set up git and git hooks on your DigitalOcean droplet to deploy your latest code on your server. Once everything's set up, you can just do `git push production master` (where `production` is a name I just gave, could be whatever you want) and your production environment will be re-deployed with the latest changes.

This article here: https://danbarber.me/using-git-for-deployment/ does a great job of getting you started, but, of course, there will be differences in your deployment code added within the hook.

**Edit:** Actually, this might be even better for you: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pretty slick solution. I usually develop in CI environments, but this definitely seems like a good smaller scale solution