# cloud9 ide and digitalocean private git repo

Tags: git, server, digital-ocean

my digitalocean box is my production environment and my cloud9 ide is my dev environment.

I want to be able to push my dev stuff(c9 ide) to my prod (digitalocean) thru git but im not sure how to do so.

I know this is possible but can all of this be done with a private repo since i dont want to have my production stuff public.

Can someone walk me thru this process or point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

All im trying to do is deploy c9 ide to digitalocean.

My process has been

1. look for git repo url on c9 ide
2. sync repo with digitalocean
3. once synced ill simply push to digitalocean and then pull

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30093080/6309 might help.

Comment: @VonC hmm still having troubles. It seems very difficult to deploy from c9 ide to digitalocean

Comment: Can you edit your question with a description of your difficulties? And what git version are you using on cloud9 and digitialocean?

Comment: @VonC all im trying to do is deploy c9 ide to digitalocean

Comment: Sure: you mention difficulties: what did you tried. What were the error messages you have seen?

Comment: @VonC no error messages im trying to find my git url on my c9 environment so i can try to have it synced to my digital ocean droplet. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not pushing from c9 (in which case you don't need your c9 url, but instead the digitalocean bare git repo url to receive your pushes)

Comment: @VonC ohhh i see, in a way i was working backwards?

Comment: Both approach are valid, but it is more natural to push your work to the destination.

Comment: @VonC thank you for everything